# How to detect older unused/Inactive sessions in our tomcat java application

Tags: java, http, session, tomcat

I want to detect older created sessions which are in ideal state(Not in used). How I can do that. I am using tomcat server in my java application.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Servers -> Your Server -> Right Click and Delete the Server

Check the "Delete unused configuration" and Delete the Server.

You are good to go.

Comment: I want a list at java side.

Comment: Can you give me more details.

Comment: I have a requirment at my application side. That I need to expire the older sessions from java side, which are older created (like 30 minutes back ) and its in ideal state.  Then how can I achieve that?